# Lambda node "hello undefined" async/await don't work?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, aws-lambda, vimeo-api

Here is my problem : I would like to call the Vimeo api inside my aws-lambda function (nodejs 12) to get some information/data about a video (like : duration, title, ...).

Here is my code :

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  let Vimeo = require("vimeo").Vimeo;
  let client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");
  console.log('client => ',

 client);
  console.log('event => ', event);
  video_id = event.video_id;
  const res = await client.request(
    {
      method: "GET",
      path: `/users/1234567890/videos/${video_id}`
    },
    function(error, body, status_code, headers) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
      console.log("body", body);
      console.log("status code");
      console.log(status_code);
      console.log("headers");

      console.log(headers);
      return body;
    }
  )
  console.log('hello', res);
  return 'ok';
};
```

To try it, I launch few tests. The lambda return `ok` so I know that my function go through all instructions but the console.log return `hello undefined`.

For me (I mean I guess) It's the callback, currently I know at 100% the `client.request(...)`return the good value if you wait enough time; but even with `async function` and `await` the lambda look too busy to wait the response of the vimeo api.

thx and have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await client.request()` doesn't return a promise to wait.

You need to do it by yourself like this:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  const Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo
  const client = new Vimeo('{client_id}', '{client_secret}', '{access_token}')
  console.log('client => ', client)
  console.log('event => ', event)
  const videoId = event.video_id
  const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.request({
      method: 'GET',
      path: `/users/1234567890/videos/${videoId}`
    },
    function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        reject(error)
        return
      }
      console.log('body', body)
      console.log('status code')
      console.log(statusCode)
      console.log('headers')

      console.log(headers)
      resolve(body)
    }
    )
  })

  console.log('hello', res)
  return 'ok'
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot it's work! as you said need promise to await !